# Technical implications of FFT spectral analysis over custom defined frequency bands

Tags: cuda, signal-processing, fft

First of all, I should mention that I'm not an expert in signal processing, but I know some of the very basics. So I apologize if this question doesn't make any sense.

Basically I want to be able to run a spectral analysis over a specific set of user-defined discrete frequency bands. Ideally I would want to capture around 50-100 different bands simultaneously. For example: the frequencies of each key on an 80-key grand piano.

Also I should probably mention that I plan to run this in a CUDA environment with about 200 cores at my disposal (Jetson TK1).

My question is: What acquisition time, sample rate, sampling frequency, etc should I use to get a high enough resolution to line up with the desired results? I don't want to choose a crazy high number like 10000 samples, so are there any tricks to minimize the number of samples while getting spectral lines within the desired bands?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use an FFT where the resolution is sufficiently high for you to uniquely discriminate all the relevant frequencies. This is toughest at the lowest notes on a piano scale, where the frequency difference between notes is smallest.

Comment: I was hoping that maybe I could break the problem down into 100 different parts (the freq bands) then run each part in parallel? What's the performance difference in running 100 FFT's with a resolution of 1 or 2 bands vs 1 FFT with 100 bands?

Comment: Well you can implement a scheme where you downsample/decimate, say for each octave, but this adds a lot of complexity and typically doesn't buy you anything performance-wise - it just gives you better time resolution at the higher frequencies. FFTs are so highly optimised that you may as well just use one large FFT and be done with it.

Comment: BTW, you'll probably get better answers if you ask a mod to migrate this question to http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The FFT result does not depend on its initialization, only on the sample rate, length, and signal input.  You don't need to use a whole FFT if you only want one frequency result.  A bandpass filter (perhaps 1 per core) for each frequency band would allow customizing each filter for the bandwidth and response desired for that frequency.

Also, for music, note pitch is very often different from spectral frequency peak.